# Set elements of passing to true whenever the parallel value of scores is a certain number or above?

Tags: java, parameters, boolean

The method (public static void processPass(boolean[] passing, double[] scores, int
length) should accept passing, scores, and length as parameters and it must set the elements of passing to true when the parallel value of
scores is 60 or more than 60.

I just started Programming II and everything got very complicated. I have the first part of the lab (which I didn't mention) but I have no clue what I did in the last method.

This website is always really helpful, I appreciate that.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    boolean[] isPassing = new boolean[100];
    double[] scores = new double[100]; 

    getData(scores);
    
}

public static int getData(double scores[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    
    File fileIn = new File("lab1data.txt");
    
    int length = 0;
            
    Scanner infile = new Scanner(fileIn);
    
    while(infile.hasNext()) {
        
    scores[length] = infile.nextDouble();
    
    length +=1;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.println(scores[i] + "\n");
    }
    
    System.out.println("Length: " + length);
    
    infile.close();
    
    return length;  
    
    
    
}

//this is what I am struggling with

public static void processPass(boolean[] passing, double[] scores, int length) {
    if(length <= 60) {
        passing[length] = true;
    }

    System.out.println(passing[length]);
    
}
```

}

Comment: First part of the lab is everything before the last method

Comment: A simple `if` check should do the trick to see if the scores are 60 or more and set the passing value accordingly `if(scores[i] <= 60){passing[i] = true;}` and you would need to put this inside a loop to check all scores `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++) { if(scores[i] <= 60) passing[i] = true; }`